Why propelling force over mass does not replace power over mass in cycling?
I opened this subject also here https://forum.cyclingnews.com/threads/when-will-power-mass-be-replaced-by-force-mass-or-acceleration-in-professional-cycling.39831/#post-3062465
Force is the power's link to reality so why not use it then?
This is the explanation:
After some years of observations, research and calculations in the cycling and rally fields, I realised that because power is synonymous with force outside of physics terminology, it gained popularity after Jes Watt defined the power as "the ability to act" with the formula Power = Force * Speed. Later Joule introduced the ENERGY concept that better explained power as a RATE of ENERGY (Power = Energy / Time).
I explained all of this in detail in this article.
At the end I did some references also to cycling but I did not had the resources to dig deeper into it.
Bottom line is: I see that cyclists use power metters and power to weight ratios. Mass is measured in kg and weight in N (Newtons). Besides the fact that weight is used as mass, this is not the big issue, but power usage is. I'm not saying that this measurement is useless. I'm just saying that it is inaccurate in comparison with Force (and acceleration) when comparing the dynamics of a material body.
Force = Mass * Acceleration
Energy (or work) = Force * Distance
The power is just a calculation between energy and time (or force and rotational speed).
The cycling world would benefit if they would look at FORCE/MASS in a period of time rather than at POWER/MASS in a period of time, and by FORCE I mean propelling (pushing) force at the back wheel's circumpherence.
EDIT.
OBS.
Please make the difference between pedal force and propelling force.

You can try the calculator (simulator) here
UPDATE:
@MaplePanda @Criggie @uhist @LeopardShark @WornChain @DavidW
Thank you all for your answers and questions.
You gave me the idea of simulating the power graph onto the force graph by using the propelling(traction) force and the speed of the object:

This shows again that power is just a layer on top of force that makes things more difficult to understand. I will continue the comparison/research with the power at the engine (crank).
This is for constant power from Tesla.


Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This seems to be more of a discussion question than one that has a concrete answer. This type of question is not considered on-topic; please see the [help/on-topic].

Ok. Thanks. I will rephrase it.

I don't understand the point here. All these variables are related. Power meters often measure the strain(a force) thus giving the torque ,t, (as crank length is known) which combined together with the angular velocity, O, measures power output. P= t*O. Power(Watts), or it's integral over time ,work(Joules), is what people want to know to have an objective measure of their effort.

@WornChain I takled the answer in the linked article. The idea is that for the same power you can have multiple forces resulting in fuzzy matching between 2 riders or between 2 measurements that are not done at the same crank rpm and that have same power. If the powermeters can export a graph of force or torque by rpm it would be great.

Yes, spinners and grinders may produce the same power at different forces/torques. But this has always been known. A force outout graph would be fine, but it would not add much except fun with numbers. Power output is what matters along with weight and friction of different kinds(air, rolling etc).

@WornChain imagine you receive from the powermeter manufacturers average propelling (not crank) force in the last 10 min interval among the 300 W for example. Then when comparing 2 measurements you can go further and evaluate which produced more force (resulting in bigger speed). Thank you.

I really don't understand. At constant speed you lose equal amounts of energy due to friction as you put in through your effort pr unit time. The greater the speed, the greater the energy loss and thus the effort(Power, i.e Jouels pr second) required to keep the speed at that level. To little power and you slow down to a slower equlibrium. To much and you accelerate to a faster equlibrium. You can produce this power with low torqe/force and high angular speed or vice versa. It does not matter, what matters is the power produced.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Forces are everywhere. Power means you're getting work done.
If you want to climb a hill, that takes energy, say 300 Wh. If your competitor is going to take 61 minutes, and you know you can put out 300 W, then you're smiling (and your drive inefficieny is smiling back at you, but that's beside the point).
A bike is made of forces. There are forces all over. The spokes are exerting forces on the rim; the frame exerts a force on the rim; etc. In contrast, the (significant) power on the bike comes from your legs, and it transfers through the drivetrain to push you forwards, modulo losses.
A rider can put out high forces for arbitrarily long periods of time, just by engaging the front brake and putting his or her full weight on one pedal. This is zero power.
The forces in the drivetrain depend on gearing. The power does not.
Cycling at high speed is difficult partly because the ground is rushing backwards beneath you as you're trying to push yourself forwards off it. This is why power is force × speed. Cutting out the speed component ignores this.
Doing everything based on forces is not wrong; you can get correct answers that way. There are even cases where working in terms of force will be easier. But, generally, power is simpler to work with directly.
Edit: looking through your article, rather than just answering the question as asked, I suspect you may not find this answer useful in its current state. It does give the reason we use power, but it doesn't address what you've written in the article.

Thanks. I marked this as answer thanks to this paragraph: >>>"Doing everything based on forces is not wrong; you can get correct answers that way. There are even cases where working in terms of force will be easier. But, generally, power is simpler to work with directly." <<< . Power is easier to work with because it is a habit. I updated the answer with some graphs that shed light on that habit...

@marius-ciclistu Power is easier to work with because it is a habit  No.  that's flat out wrong.  You can't restrict analysis to only force - go compute the force when you're trying to tow a bus with your bicycle - and going nowhere.  You can stand on the pedals all day - nothing happens, nothing changes.  You could even replace your body with a properly weighted mannequin and everything could stay static for years.  Doing something requires movement, and movement means velocity, and force with velocity is literally the very definition of power.

Doing everything based on forces is not wrong; you can get correct answers that way.  But as you stated, you still must include velocity and can't use only force.  If you rearrange your calculations to avoid explicitly using power, once force and velocity are both involved, the power element may be implicit, but it's still there.  FWIW, I tend to find power/energy calculations much easier than using forces.

@AndrewHenle All the simulations from the calculator are made without taking into account the energy rate (power). Power appears in graph 1 and 3 just as 5th wheel to the carriage ( just a multiplication , not measurable). Graph 7,  Energy is calculated from Force * Distance. Using the energy rate is overcomplication that increases the calculation error margin ( I tried it ). About the bycicle. If I use the right gear ratio, steel wheel + frame and enough bike weight for enough friction force, I can tow the bus ;). It is all about force.

@AndrewHenle Energy is transformed into force, force that generates movement. Power is just the calculation of the rate by which the energy is transformed into force.

@marius-ciclistu It is all about force Again, that's wrong.  Force is useless without movement, and once things are moving, energy is required.  And the rate of the energy being supplied is power.  You get no movement without power.  You can apply all the force you want, and if it doesn't move, the force is irrelevant.  And once movement starts, without an energy supply - a source of power - the force will go to zero and the movement will stop.  You can bandy words all you want, but you can't remove the requirement for energy and therefore power to effect movement.

@AndrewHenle Lets agree that power is a consequence of force and force is the cause of power. You are mixing resultant force with force when you speak about movement. If resultant force it not greather than 0 of course there is no movement.

I have an idea.
Typically, on flatland, you would be riding with a 50-tooth chainring / 15-tooth sprocket combination. If you produce 200 Newtons of force with 0.17 meter cranks, that's 34 newton-meters. The gearing changes that to 10.2 newton-meters. The 338 mm radius wheel then gives about 30.2 Newtons of force.
Put a 11-teeth chainring in the front.
Use a 51-tooth sprocket.
Change the wheel to a Brompton-sided one with 211 mm radius.
Then you would have 157.64 Newton meters after gearing, or 747.11 Newtons at the ground contact point of the rear wheel.
So, if with 11/51 gearing instead of 50/15 gearing and a smaller wheel, you can increase your force by nearly 25x, why doesn't everybody do that?
It's because wheel sizes and gearings don't change power. They change force. But they don't change power.
With ridiculously low gearing, you would have to pedal so fast you can't pedal that fast, to go even at walking speed.
So clearly, power is the important parameter here.

I received this answer so many times since 2016.  You are right up to the conclusion about using power. You produced yesterday 300 w at the crank so you have 300 w at the back wheel (we ignore loses from chain, tyre etc). Today you produced the same in the same interval of 10 minutes on the same road(climb) lets say.  Yesterday you had 20 km/h average and today 21km/h. W being N*Rad/s => you generated more propelling force (with less pedal force but bigger crank rpm) today than yesterday while keeping the same power. Power is usable but not clearer than propelling force when comparing.

@marius-ciclistu if you've been asking the same question for 8 years and getting the same answer "many times" then perhaps the example needs modifying.  Does it help to make the system stationary, perhaps a winch or a pump ?

@Criggie I ask for so long because I want to see if I missed something in my simulations as a cyclist and rally driver. The torque curve by rpm is the thing people miss. No engine or human can produce a horizontal torque graph (including electric motors). Also the ones replying don't bother rewiewing CAREFULLY what I wrote and fallback to what they know from their history, forcing me to reply and dismountle their CONCLUSIONS based on historical knowledge. No one is wrong in what they are saying. But they don't stop and think for a moment  if what I'm asking can help or not.

@marius-ciclistu I suppose some people may be interested in knowing their pedaling force (perhaps some sprinter is interested in their ability to lift weights or something), but for most people the limiting factor when cycling is their aerobic capacity (related to rate of calorie burn) and for that, power is the natural metric. You are a food to shaft work conversion machine—the actual force involved is kinda irrelevant.

@MaplePanda I ask abot propelling force at the back wheel outher diameter not about pedal force. I guess the answer is one of these 3: it is hard to calculate or measure that average propelling force OR they don't want to OR worse they don't understand it.

@marius-ciclistu The two values are related by the net gear ratio--there's nothing special about knowing the circumferential tractive force.

@MaplePanda propelling force divided by mass gives acceleration. That is so special about it.  And propelling force is not resultant force. It does not include the resistive forces like air friction, rolling resistance or gravity component.

@MaplePanda I suppose some people may be interested in knowing their pedaling force (perhaps some sprinter is interested in their ability to lift weights or something) A track cycling standing start is probably the only thing where the force a cyclist can put on the pedals matters.  And if you do win that, everyone else just gets to use you for your draft - and go just as fast with lower power requirements...
